# promise pending error in mongodb and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have written node.js code for getting some number using mongodb database.this is my code for that

```
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mongomart', function(err, db) {

    assert.equal(null, err);

    var numItems=db.collection('item').find({"category":category}).count();

    callback(numItems);
});
```

This mongodb query runs correct on mongo shell but it is giving error when using with node.js

```
Promise <Pending>
```

I don't know what is this "promise" ? Please help..

Comment: How is that an error? Looks like a return value on the REPL to me.

Answer (score 9):

node.js code is asynchronous so that `numItems` won't contain count of items - it rather contains `Promise` that contains count of items when resolved. You definitely have to master the basics of node.js and asynchronous programming. Try to modify your code like this

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mongomart', function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  db.collection('item').find({"category":category}).count()
    .then(function(numItems) {
      console.log(numItems); // Use this to debug
      callback(numItems);
    })
});
```

For native `Promise` check out documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Also look at `bluebird` promises https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird

Comment: I've red this book http://www.amazon.com/Node-js-Action-Mike-Cantelon/dp/1617290572/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1456324024&sr=1-1&keywords=node

Comment: I also recomend to master `express`. On this topic I've red this http://www.amazon.com/Pro-Express-js-Node-js-Framework-Development/dp/1484200381/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1456324142&sr=1-2&keywords=express

Answer (score 2):

A [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is a substitute temporary value that is given while you wait on the real value. To get the real value do

```
numItems.then(function (value) { callback(value) });
```

Or better yet, return the promise from your function, and let they implement it using the Promises pattern, instead of the callback pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Don't know if it's still relevant to you, but this is what solved it for me:

```
var category = 'categoryToSearch';
var cursor = db.collection('item').find({'category':category});

cursor.count(function (err, num) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    return num;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I drove myself bananas trying to solve a similar problem, where the `document.save()` option just gave `Promise{pending}` no matter what I did. Here's what I did:

- Change `(req,res)` to `async(req,res)`.
- Change `var post = doc.save()` to `var post = await doc.save()`.

Finally, log in to MongoDB web, and change accessible IP addresses to `0.0.0.0` (all addresses). Not doing this can cause issues sometimes even when your IP is whitelisted.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mongomart', async (err, db) => {

    assert.equal(null, err);

    var numItems= await db.collection('item').find({"category":category}).count();

    callback(numItems);
});
```

(adding the `await` and turn this function to `async function`)